# Navigation bar extended clickable area

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I've been playing around with HTML and CSS and I've got a problem.
How can I make the padding left-right have link property too?

```
<div class="baraNavigatie">
            <ul class="lista">
                <li><a href="default.html">Bine ati venit!</a></li>
                <li><a href="cinesunt.html">Cine sunt?</a></li>
                <li><a href="ceofer.html">Ce ofer?</a></li>
                <li><a href="evenimente.html">Evenimente</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

^a part of HTML code^

```
li{
    font-size:25px;
    display:inline;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:40px;
}
.baraNavigatie{
    height:33px;
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'Avant Garde', Avantgarde, 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
li:hover{
    background-color:#6a92ff;
}
```

^CSS^

Sorry for my bad english also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy - just apply the `padding-left` and `padding-right` to the `<a>` element instead of the `<li>`. [The `<a>` tag creates a clickable link](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/a/).

Try this:

```
li {
  font-size:25px;
  display:inline;
}
.baraNavigatie {
  height:33px;
  background-color:blue;
  text-align:center;
}
li a {
  padding-left:40px;
  padding-right:40px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family: 'Avant Garde', Avantgarde, 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}
li:hover {
  background-color:#6a92ff;
}
```